# Replacing random characters in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, replace, ssis, expression, etl

I created a derived column expression in SSIS that replaces random characters, which appear in a description column when the package is run. The expression works  except for a ? mark that appears at the beginning of the description when the package is run.

I have reviewed the source table description column, and can’t locate any issues there. I have included the expression I am using. Is there something I am missing.

Any assistance is appreciated.

```
(DT_STR,4000,1252)SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(DCCDescNew,"&#58;",":"),"</p>"," "),"</div>"," "),60,4000)
```

Comment: That expression doesn't replace a `?` character. The character might be a legit question mark or it might be a placeholder for a character that can't be displayed in whatever client tool you are using to view it

Comment: As @Nick.McDermaid points out you dont replace a ? character. If you wanna replace placeholder values you should use "\?"

Comment: "\?" does not resolve in the expression. Any other thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `?` can be done with a simple replace function:

```
REPLACE([Col],"?"," ")
```

Your derived column expression should be

```
(DT_STR,4000,1252)SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(DCCDescNew,"&#58;",":"),"</p>"," "),"</div>"," "),"?"," "),60,4000)
```

If this is not working, check that the question mark is not a unicode character

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I tried the HTML Entity (decimal) and HTML Entity (hex) too, but no luck.

The ? does not appear in the data source, so I know the issue is not on that end.

I found a VB script that looks promising, but have other issues in the package to resolve before I can try it.